# Recent Green card holder. From US, how to Transfer money from my Indian SB AC to my recently opened checking account in US

Tags: united-states, india, money-transfer

Recent US Green card holder not NRI, as came to US just 2 months back.

After coming to US, how can I Transfer money from my own savings bank account in India (No NRE or NRO A/C) to my recently opened checking account in US?

Comment: Convert your savings account to NRO

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close this question as a duplicate because it is _not_ a duplicate of the one chosen by Dheer, Rupert Morrish and Pete B., and it has been reopened. The full answer was in a pair of comments by Dheer ("convert your accounts to NRO" and "Possible duplicate of  _Transfer ..._" ), only one of which has survived the closure.  A more extensive explanation of Dheer's surviving comment and a reference to his excellent answer to _Transfer..._ is given in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You are now an NRI (NonResident Indian) in the eyes of the Government of India and as such, not entitled to hold a regular savings account in India, even if you have been holding one all your life before you moved to the US. Indian banks are forbidden from letting NRIs hold and operate regular savings accounts but have the out that until the bank *knows* that you are an NRI, it doesn't need to do anything about the matter.  So, if you never filed a change of address telling the state Bank of India (SBI) that you are now in the US (or sent them a change of address form telling them that your new address is your parents' home address in India, etc), SBI will let you operate the regular savings account without any hassles. What SBI will *not* let you do is transfer any of that money to your own account in the US.

So, as @Dheer says in a comment, the first thing you need to do is tell SBI that you are now an NRI and that you want to convert your regular savings account into an NRO account.  They will "be happy to assist you" in doing so because they too are required by law or Reserve Bank of India regulations to change such accounts to NRO status as soon as possible.  Of course, this being SBI, you will most likely have to go through incredible contortions and paperwork, sending them notarized copies of your green card which notarization might need apostille certification by the Secretary of State of the US State in which you reside, followed by certification from the local Indian Consulate that the Secretary of State certification is indeed legitimate (that is, it is not something that you printed out on your color laser printer) etc.  Once you have done all this, you should follow the advice given by Dheer in his answer to [Transfer Money from my account in India to my account in the USA](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/73116/5760)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  We are aware about NRI status and NRO/NRE accounts, but I thought you had to wait 6 months after arriving in the US before you would get NRI status.  Are you saying we can get it switched sooner?

Comment: @jmort253 If you have a US green card, you are automatically a NRI; no need to wait for six months to officially attain NRI status in the eyes of the Government of India. If you came on a student visa or work visa, and expect to be in the US (on elsewhere outside India), you can wait for the required 182 days before you convert all the accounts you left behind in India into NRO accounts, or you can start the process right away since it can well be six months before the banks will actually convert your regular resident accounts into NRO accounts.  Brokerage/Dmat accounts are another issue.